# Javascript variable is undefined or not working inside the Morris.Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined

Consider me as a newbie in js. I am having a problem in accessing the javascript variable inside the Morris.Bar function.

When i do the following, i get the correct output. It works as a charm:

```
<div id="graph"></div>
<script>
  Morris.Bar({
    element: 'graph',
    data: [{x:'2015-06-12 00:00:00.0', y: 1025},
           {x:'2015-06-12 00:00:00.0', y: 1025},
           {x:'2015-06-12 00:00:00.0', y: 1025},
           {x:'2015-06-12 00:00:00.0', y: 1025},
           {x:'2015-06-12 00:00:00.0', y: 1025},
          ],
    xkey: 'x',
    ykeys: 'y',
    labels: ['Y']
  }).on('click', function(i, row){
    console.log(i, row);
  });
</script>
```

But when i use the same thing with the variable i didn't get the output as:

```
<div id="graph"></div>
<script>
  var datatable = "[{x:'2015-06-12 00:00:00.0', y: 1025},{x:'2015-06-12 00:00:00.0', y: 1025},{x:'2015-06-12 00:00:00.0', y: 1025},{x:'2015-06-12 00:00:00.0', y: 1025},{x:'2015-06-12 00:00:00.0', y: 1025}]";
  Morris.Bar({
    element: 'graph',
    data: this.datatable,
    xkey: 'x',
    ykeys: 'y',
    labels: ['Y']
  }).on('click', function(i, row){
    console.log(i, row);
  });
</script>
```

Please can someone help me with this. It is giving me a lot of trouble.

It shows "undefined" inside the graph.

Comment: and without the `this`?

Comment: datatable is now a string, not an object. Just need to remove the double quote around the string to back to a raw object.

Comment: JSON.parse(datatable)

Comment: @JNF without 'this' is also not working.

Comment: @Hacketo Thanks so much it works fine. You have saved me a lot of time.